# Refreshing a query every x time

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I'm currently doing a monitoring app, I have a sql query which give all the data that I have to put in my ListView but now I want to refresh my query every one minute for example. This is how it looks like. Can anyone help me please?

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"path\query.txt");              

OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(text, conn);               
OracleDataReader data = command.ExecuteReader();

while (data.Read())
```

Comment: You can use cache expiry limit to the query

Answer (score 0):

You could use a timer to execute it after 1 min, just like this:

```
private Timer timer; 

public void InitTimer()
{
    timer= new Timer();
    timer.Elapsed += OnTimerTick;
    timer.Interval = 1000; // Remember this is milliseconds
    timer.Start();
}

private void OnTimerTick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"path\query.txt");              

    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(text, conn);               
    OracleDataReader data = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (data.Read())
    ...
}
```

Comment: With your method I have to put all my main code in a private void and it doesn't work

Comment: Why would you need to return anything apart from `void` to refresh your view ? Are you using MVVM ?

Comment: The Method of @Juan Carlos Rodriguez is exactly the way to go. You can call your public code from `OnTimerTick`, no problem.

Comment: That's it @linuxrocks... You don't need to copy your method to the `OnTimerTick` method, you can just call it from there but I'm afraid he/she is not using MVVM and if he/she tries to update the `ItemsSource` from a `Elapsed` event it will throw an exception.